# Apache POI Replace String in Word

Tags: java, replace, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

I've recently been working on an automated system to make and print out letters to post. The system works as follows:

- I create a file, with all the information in it, and replace some things with %... placeholders. For example, %name, %date, etc.
- When I run the application, I can select a name from the list, and it automatically loads the document, replaces all the placeholders with information supplied by a MySQL database, and prints out the document. For testing purposes, I'm just saving the document for now.

I've found some tutorials on the internet, and found a code that suited my needs. Unfortunately, this code only works for Word versions older than 2007 (.doc files). What would I change for 2007+ compatibility (.docx files)?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/Users/Jasper/Desktop/document.doc");
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);

        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);

        Range range = doc.getRange();
        range.replaceText("%name", "Jasper");
        range.replaceText("%age", "17");

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/Users/Jasper/Desktop/document2.doc");
        doc.write(fos);

        fis.close();
        fos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13752652/506005) I used this solution to automate generation of documents and it has been used since more than 1 year on production.

Comment: @HaucemBerrayana That seems like an awfully complicated way of achieving a simple task...

Comment: It's not a very simple task if you ask me. This code works perfectly. Just use it as it is. You can even work with styles, etc if you wanna do something advanced