# Create Word Document with Java

Tags: java, ms-word

I have default table model fetch with data from database and i want to print in doc word as a table. How to achieve that. See the code below:

```
    try {
        try {
            con = connCC.getDBconnection();
             } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(CustomerSR.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        stm = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("Select * From Appointment");

        while (rs.next()) {

            for (int col = 0; col < 1; col++) {
                rowData.add(rs.getString(1));
                rowData.add(rs.getString(2));
                rowData.add(rs.getString(3));
                rowData.add(rs.getString(4));
                rowData.add(rs.getString(5));
            }
            model.addRow(rowData);
        }
            window.display(model);
           //window.display(names, phones, addresses);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: I would start with Apache POI, eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266844/apache-poi-word-tutorial

Comment: I don't believe Java can do this on its own. You will need to look for an API to use.

Comment: Thanks Tricky12, can you suggest any API?

Comment: As @rkosegi suggested, Apache POI would be a good option to start with.

Comment: Aha i am using apache POI and i can create a doc but the data there are grouped together have no meaning. So my question was how to print the data that i got from database in table word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above comments, I see that you are already using Apache POI. If I understand correctly, you want to input data from a database into a table on a word document. Take a look at this tutorial on creating tables in word with Apache POI:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_tables.htm

You can set the text directly with the data that you retrieve from the database. I can post an example if you need it, but the tutorial does a pretty good job of showing what you need to do.

----UPDATE----

Sorry that it took me a while, went to lunch with the wife. Try this:

```
// Blank Document
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

// Write the Document in file system
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("create_table.docx"));

// Create table
XWPFTable table = document.createTable();

// Table row
XWPFTableRow tableRow;

int rowCount = model.getRowCount() - 1;
int colCount = model.getColumnCount() - 1;

// Iterate through rows
for (int row = 0; row <= rowCount; row++) {
    tableRow = table.getRow(row);

    // Iterate through columns
    for (int col = 0; col <= colCount; col++) {
        tableRow.getCell(col).setText((String) model.getValueAt(row, col));

        // If more columns, add cell
        if (row == 0 && col < colCount) {
            tableRow.addNewTableCell();
        }
    }

    // If more rows, add row
    if (row < rowCount) {
        table.createRow();
    }
}

// Write to word document and close file.        
document.write(out);
out.close();
```

Comment: JagerSOE u got my point, i did similar like this tutorial but still l am unable to fetch one data in one cell, my code that is in question fetches data one column in one cell?

Comment: You mean it's putting the entire column's worth of data into 1 cell?

Comment: JagerSOE  Yes, and the data are not meaningfull

Comment: How are you inserting it into each cell?

Comment: And why the default table model, are you displaying this data in a table on a GUI as well?

Comment: Yes, because there will be two choice for kind of report.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a coded example. Let me know if it works for you.