# How extract word between tag with open office library?

Tags: java, openoffice.org

How can I extract word in binary file or .doc file with open office library in Java?

I can't find good documentation or example of how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache POI Word tutorial.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266844/apache-poi-word-tutorial)

Comment: Not really, because I don't search and replace I need juste to search and extract to save it in a String list

Comment: In your link I see I can replace word but not how extract the word only like in the file there is <%%WordToExtract%%> and when I use this librairy the method return WordToExtract who is put in a list. It's for search all word between tags